# Probably super simple python plotting warning using matplotlib

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, matplotlib

I'm setting up python and I'm sure I've screwed something up. I have python 2.7, pip, and the c compiler for python.  I've installed matplotlib and a couple other modules with pip, and I'd like to run the following code:

```
from pylab import *
t = arange(0.0, 2.0, 0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)
plot(t, s)
show()
```

The warning message I receive is:

```
Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 1611
    return np.all(self.get_matrix() == other.get_matrix())
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in equal
```

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling.  I have the following modules:

> - matplotlib 1.4.3
> - numpy 1.10.0.post2
> - pip 7.1.2
> - pyparsing 2.0.3
> - python-dateutil 2.4.2
> - pytz 2015.6
> - setuptools 18.3.2
> - six 1.10.0
> - wheel 0.26.0

Comment: A warning usually doesn't mean an error. I get these a lot when I plot, say, an array divided by other, and there is some division by zero. Usually this means some part of a line won't be plotted, for example. In your case, the equality comparer buried inside matplotlib is getting some noise from the matrices, it seems.

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah, I understand it's not an error, but I was hoping to fix it anyhow.